# I got an "cannot find -lOpenGL::OpenGL" error when make install partio

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

When I install the partio it shows the following error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenGL::OpenGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/tools/CMakeFiles/partview.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target 'src/tools/partview' failed
make[2]: *** [src/tools/partview] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:967: recipe for target 'src/tools/CMakeFiles/partview.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/tools/CMakeFiles/partview.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When I search the internet I barely see any information regard to -lOpenGL::OpenGL. I have seen OpenGL::GLU or GL. But I havent seen OpenGL::OpenGL yet. So I don't know how to solve this.

I am using the cmake version exactly 3.15.0.
Is there any solution to this? Anything would help.

Comment: That target is provided by [FindOpenGL.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html). See the note at the bottom of the page. Can you check the contents of each of the variables? What OpenGL implementation does your system use?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The library you're looking for is called `libGL.so`, not `libOpenGL.so` or similar. To link it, add `-lGL` to your command line and delete references to `OpenGL::OpenGL` on the command line. (If you're still having troubles, show us your whole build command line.)

That said, OpenGL is a C-based library, so C++ constructs like `OpenGL::OpenGL` (presumably a constructor of a class) will not be found therein. Or perhaps that's a reference to CMake, in which case my answer would need to change significantly.

Comment: OpenGL::OpenGL is a valid Cmake target; it has nothing to do with C++. See my comment.

Comment: @Botje: Right (hence the last sentence in my answer). There was no indication in the OP that CMake was in use or not.

Comment: The `CMakeFiles` in the error output gave it away for me, but it is easy to miss.